# mountable engine + capybara (with rspec) + main_app.helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my `Admin::ApplicationController` (which is a mountable engine) , I include main_app's helepr methods like this: `helper ::ApplicationHelper` .

But when I run capybara + rspec tests, I get a error like this: `undefined method 'foo' for #<#<Class:0x007fe9c14821e8>:0x007fe9c1485aa0>`

How can I fix this issue? Thanks on advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

- create `SharedHelper` in my main_app
- edit rails_helper.rb in my admin engine as following

> ```
> require '../app/helpers/shared_helper'
>
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>   config.include SharedHelper
> end
> ```